# configure an existing controller to display devise notifications: undefined local variable or method `resource'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, controller

I have created a Rails 3 app with devise and i also have a controller called 'account' . When an user signs in with devise's sign in view , he's redirected to a view of account controller. So the notifications od devise "sign in successful" etc are not displayed. When i tried adding

`<%= devise_error_messages! %>`

to this view  It gave an error

**NameError in Account#welcome 
undefined local variable or method `resource' for #<#:0x4e9fe70>**

Can anyone pls tell me how to make this account controller display devise's notifications??
I tried reading the docs in github but didnt help..
I guess we have do modify routes file as its showing error in resources..

**Update1:**

*Layout file:*

```
<div id="maincontent">
      <div class="entry">
        <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
        <%= content_tag :section, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}", :class => "flash" %>
        <% end %>
        <!--<p class="commentbar"> Signup</p>-->
        <%= yield %>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you installed Devise, there will be a block of guide. One paragraph is about the messages:

> Ensure you have flash messages in app/views/layouts/application.html.erb.
>        For example:

```
   <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
   <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
```

So, to display success messages/notice, use

```
<%= notice %>
<%= alert %>
```

These two are also Rails default helper to show flash messages. So you are fine with both Devise and other normal flash messages with this setting.

Comment: I have the standard flash stuff in my layout file.. So it works fine when the view is a devise view like sign in or register . But after sign in it is redirected to other view which is not devise and there nothing is displayed. Updated my layout file code snippet

Comment: @akshatha, I don't understand your point. You said *"So the notifications od devise "sign in successful" etc are not displayed."* but now you say there is no problem. Besides `alert` is almost same as `devise_error_message` which all use @instance.errors. You don't need duplicate if you've already use `alert`.

Comment: Hi Billy, my point is devise notifications on devise controllers views like users/sign_in users/sign_up works.. but when i redirect after sign in to a view like account/welcome or account/help etc the notifications like "signed in successfully" doesnt appear as <%= devise_error_messages! %> is raising an error as i have mentioned in my question

Comment: @akshatha, I see. Why don't you just remove `<%= devise_error_messages! %>`. You don't need that because you've already have flash error messages in your layout.

Comment: Yeah i tried.. But then it doesnt display all the time! Sometimes it does sometimes it doesnt! And when it displays it does it twice .. because of flash and yield!